# Angular2 to Asp.net Core Webapi IFormFile is null

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am using angular2 with asp.net core webapi. Using the following code to send file information. IFormFile is always null. I have used same name in post input and in api method parameter, still no luck. Please help me.

**FormData**

```
 this.formData.append("file", f,f.name);
```

**Component method**

```
public UploadFiles() {
        console.log("Form Data:" + this.formData);

        let saved: boolean = false;
        this.claimsService
            .UploadFiles(this.formData)
            .subscribe(data => {
                saved = data;
            }, error => {
                console.log(error)
                swal(error);

            })
    }
```

**Service Method**

```
UploadFiles(data: FormData): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.ExecuteFilePost("Upload/Upload", data);
    }
```

**Base Service Method:**

```
public ExecuteFilePost(action: string, data: FormData) {
        let _body = data;

        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': undefined});

        let url = this._baseUrl + action;

        let requestoptions: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers,
        });

        console.log('req url:' + url);
        return this.http.post(url,_body,requestoptions)
            .share()
            .map((res: Response) => {
                if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
                    throw new Error('This request has failed ' + res.status);
                }
                else {
                    return res.json();
                }
            });

    }
```

**WebApi Method**

```
[HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Upload")]
        public async Task Upload(IFormFile file)
        {

            var uploads = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
           // foreach (var file in files)
           // {
                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    }
                }
           // }
        }
```

Chrome request screens
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a31PO.png)

Comment: I was able to fix the issue. I have done the following things. 
Removed { 'Content-Type': undefined}
Added 'Accept', 'application/json'

And ConfigureServices->services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
            });

Configure-> app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is old, but maybe for others. You can do things like this:

HTML:

```
<input #fileInput type="file" multiple />
<button (click)="addFile()">Add</button>
```

Component:

```
@ViewChild("fileInput") fileInput;

    addFile(): void {
        let fi = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
        if (fi.files) {
            let fileToUpload = fi.files; 
            this.settingsService
                .upload(fileToUpload)
                .subscribe(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                });
        }
    }
```

Service:

```
upload(files: any) {
        let formData = new FormData();
        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            formData.append("files", files[i]);
        }

        return this.http
            .post(fileUploadApi, formData)
            .map(response => this.extractData(response as Response))
            .catch(error => this.httpErrorHandlerService.responseError(error));
    }
```

Web API

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("Upload")]
        public IActionResult UploadFiless([FromForm] IFormFileCollection files)
        {
            try
            {
                return this.Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return this.BadRequest();
            }
        }
```